# Group By and Sum using Underscore/Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js, lodash

I have JSON like this:

```
[
  {
     platformId: 1,
     payout: 15,
     numOfPeople: 4
  },
  {
     platformId: 1,
     payout: 12,
     numOfPeople: 3

  },
  {
     platformId: 2,
     payout: 6,
     numOfPeople: 5

  },
  {
     platformId: 2,
     payout: 10,
     numOfPeople: 1
  },

]
```

And I want to Group it by `platformId` with sum of `payout` and `numOfPeople`.

I.e. in result I want JSON like this:

```
[
  "1": {
     payout: 27,
     numOfPeople: 7
   },

  "2": {
     payout: 16,
     numOfPeople: 6
  }
]
```

I tried to use `underscore.js`'s `_.groupBy` method, and it groups fine, but how I can get the SUM of objects properties values like I demonstrated above?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "sum of the object's properties"? Are you trying to sum `payout` and `numOfPeople` for each or `payout` of each and `numOfPeople` of each separately?

Comment: @Whymarrh exactly. I.e. I want sum of `payouts` and sum of `numOfPeople`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this without Underscore:

```
var result = data.reduce(function(acc, x) {
  var id = acc[x.platformId]
  if (id) {
    id.payout += x.payout
    id.numOfPeople += x.numOfPeople
  } else {
    acc[x.platformId] = x
    delete x.platformId
  }
  return acc
},{})
```

But why would you want an object with numeric keys? You could convert it back to a collection:

```
var toCollection = function(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj)
    .sort(function(x, y){return +x - +y})
    .map(function(k){return obj[k]})
}

toCollection(result)
```

Note that objects are mutated, so you may to clone them first if you want to maintain the original data.

Comment: Accepted answer, but not answering the question!

Comment: Pure JS sucks, i think

Comment: "why would you want an object with numeric keys" => because in the context of the question, those ids could just as well be UUIDs, or any unique id. And they aren't guaranteed to be sequential either. Therefore, any assumption of nice ids should be dropped, and having the ids as keys is once again a fine solution.

Answer (score 45):

Here's a [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) solution to this kind of problem. It's similar to Underscore, but with some more advanced features.

```js
const data = [{
    platformId: 1,
    payout: 15,
    numOfPeople: 4
  },
  {
    platformId: 1,
    payout: 12,
    numOfPeople: 3

  },
  {
    platformId: 2,
    payout: 6,
    numOfPeople: 5

  },
  {
    platformId: 2,
    payout: 10,
    numOfPeople: 1
  },
];

const ans = _(data)
  .groupBy('platformId')
  .map((platform, id) => ({
    platformId: id,
    payout: _.sumBy(platform, 'payout'),
    numOfPeople: _.sumBy(platform, 'numOfPeople')
  }))
  .value()

console.log(ans);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tip: This uses the 'seq' or chaining functionality of lodash as opposed to static functions. In the docs this is explained in the 'Seq' section https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#lodash

Comment: If you're not familiar with chaining in lodash, especially if you're trying to use tree-shaking or `lodash-es` then read this https://medium.com/making-internets/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba

Answer (score 14):

I tried to do this in the functional way, and the result was like this

```
console.log(_.chain(data)
    .groupBy("platformId")
    .map(function(value, key) {
        return [key, _.reduce(value, function(result, currentObject) {
            return {
                payout: result.payout + currentObject.payout,
                numOfPeople: result.numOfPeople + currentObject.numOfPeople
            }
        }, {
            payout: 0,
            numOfPeople: 0
        })];
    })
    .object()
    .value());
```

Comment: I voted up, but this is still returning array of array. Can you get it to the final result that he is trying to look at?

Answer (score 7):

In the spirit of lodash one liners

```
  _.map(_.groupBy(your_list, 'group_by'), (o,idx) => { return { id: idx, 
summed: _.sumBy(o,'sum_me') }})
```

Comment: @hardikbeladiya this is tested and works. I use it in production with no issue. Where do you see the issue with the logic? Map isn't iterating, it is simply mapping the value you want to group by, where the aggregate of the param is being totalled by the sumBy...

Answer (score 5):

A (in my opinion) nice functional way using underscore.js:

```
var sum = function(t, n) { return t + n; };
_.mapObject(
    _.groupBy(data, 'platformId'),
    function(values, platformId) {
        return {
            payout: _.reduce(_.pluck(values, 'payout'), sum, 0),
            numOfPeople: _.reduce(_.pluck(values, 'numOfPeople'), sum, 0)
        };
    }
);
```

Comment: Cleanest and most straightforward way to do what is actually asked.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Input 
[{
  "platformId": 1,
  "payout": 15,
  "numOfPeople": 4
}, {
  "platformId": 1,
  "payout": 12,
  "numOfPeople": 3
}, {
  "platformId": 2,
  "payout": 6,
  "numOfPeople": 5
}, {
  "platformId": 2,
  "payout": 10,
  "numOfPeople": 1
}]


//Output
{
 "1": {
    "payout": 43,
    "numOfPeople": 13
 },
 "2": {
    "payout": 43,
    "numOfPeople": 13
 }
}


// Code
output = _.reduce(input, function(acc, val, key) {
  acc[val.platformId] = {
     payout: _.sum(a, 'payout'),
     numOfPeople: _.sum(a, 'numOfPeople')
   };
  return acc;
  }, {});
```

Comment: Can you explain what you have solved with this answer?

Comment: Just tried to get the out in required format with loadash.

Comment: What does `a` mean in the above solution? This code fails because it's `undefined`.