# Is there a function or method in javascript that would amalgamate multiple objects?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, object, data-manipulation

I have a postgres database I query from that returns me back a set of objects from my query
The stack I'm using is node express, javascript, and I'm using websockets to catch the transfer the data. I'm trying to compile the objects back into 
This is the code I use after I fetch the data from the database

```
`socket.on('get2GTPmatch', function(team2){
  for(var i = 0; i<team2.rows.length; i++){
    console.log(team2.rows[i]);
  }
});'




Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fnx", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "FALLEN", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "coldzera", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fer", kills: 3, deaths: 0, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fnx", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "FALLEN", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "coldzera", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fer", kills: 3, deaths: 1, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fnx", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "FALLEN", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "coldzera", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fer", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fnx", kills: 2, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "FALLEN", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "coldzera", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fer", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fnx", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "FALLEN", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "coldzera", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fer", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fnx", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "FALLEN", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "coldzera", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fer", kills: 3, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fnx", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "FALLEN", kills: 2, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "coldzera", kills: 2, deaths: 1, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fer", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fnx", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "FALLEN", kills: 2, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "coldzera", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fer", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fnx", kills: 2, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "FALLEN", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "coldzera", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fer", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 2, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fnx", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "FALLEN", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "coldzera", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fer", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 2, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fnx", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "FALLEN", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "coldzera", kills: 2, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fer", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fnx", kills: 2, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "FALLEN", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "coldzera", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fer", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fnx", kills: 2, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "FALLEN", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "coldzera", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fer", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 2, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fnx", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "FALLEN", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "coldzera", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fer", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 2, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fnx", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 2}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "FALLEN", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "coldzera", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fer", kills: 4, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fnx", kills: 0, deaths: 0, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "FALLEN", kills: 0, deaths: 0, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "coldzera", kills: 3, deaths: 0, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fer", kills: 1, deaths: 0, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 0, deaths: 0, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 0, deaths: 0, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fnx", kills: 0, deaths: 0, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "FALLEN", kills: 1, deaths: 1, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "coldzera", kills: 2, deaths: 0, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fer", kills: 0, deaths: 0, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 1, deaths: 0, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 1, deaths: 0, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fnx", kills: 1, deaths: 0, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "FALLEN", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "coldzera", kills: 0, deaths: 0, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fer", kills: 1, deaths: 0, assists: 1}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 0, deaths: 0, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "TACO", kills: 0, deaths: 0, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "fnx", kills: 0, deaths: 0, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "FALLEN", kills: 2, deaths: 1, assists: 0}
Object {name: "Luminosity", alias: "coldzera", kills: 0, deaths: 1, assists: 0}
```

Is there a simple way to combine all the objects I get back into a single object with {name: , alias:, kills:(total of all objects under the same name/alias), :deaths:(same as kills), assists:(same as kills)} ?

Thank you for your help. I'm still a noob. Sorry.

Comment: What's wrong with simply iterating through the objects and populating the values of a new object from there?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047463/group-by-and-sum-using-underscore-lodash?rq=1

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific? Sorry I'm still very new to javascript. Would I use a .forEach loop?

Comment: @powerup7 Think of how you'd do it in any other language. Go through `team2.rows`, create a new object everytime you find a new combination of name and alias, update the corresponding value of kills, aliases, etc. every time you encounter an object with the same name and alias. Use a set or a map to query for name/alias combinations.

Comment: Ok thanks for the all the help. I'll dig into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
client.query(
    "SELECT teams.name AS team, players.alias, SUM(kills) AS kills, SUM(deaths) AS deaths, SUM(assists) AS assists FROM rounds \
    JOIN player_rounds ON rounds.id=player_rounds.round_id \
    JOIN players ON player_rounds.player_id=players.steam_id \
    JOIN teams ON players.team=teams.id \
    WHERE rounds.game_id='B3Il5v' \
    GROUP BY players.alias, teams.name\
    ORDER BY teams.name",
    function(err,results){
      if(err) {
        return console.error('error occurred');
      }
      // console.log(results);
      socket.emit('getKDAmatch', results)
```

});

It was the fact that I had a problem with with SQL group by. When I just used group by teams.name it would throw an error for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the Object.assign() method:

```
var objs_merged = {};
socket.on('get2GTPmatch', function(team2){
    for(var i = 0; i < team2.rows.length; i++) {
        objs_merged = Object.assign(objs_merged, team2.rows[i]);
    }
});
```

If you want to have one object with summed properties, well that would have been much easier to do with your database query.

Comment: I did it through a long sql query then. I just needed to rest and not bang my head for 10 hours a day. :)

Comment: Glad you figured it out. It's a lot easier to group and sum through your query.