# How to group by - Sum in react-native?

Tags: react-native

*I have objects  and I want to get all object's  total "Tutar" object. How can I do this ?.*

*Look image :*

[image]

Comment: Something like [`Array.map();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a third part library like lodash?

https://lodash.com/docs/#groupBy

Check this thread :)

[Group By and Sum using Underscore/Lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047463/group-by-and-sum-using-underscore-lodash)

Comment: Thx david, but I dont understand what _. means ? I am new to react-native

Comment: `_.groupBy([6.1, 4.2, 6.3], Math.floor);` means `Lodash.groupBy([6.1, 4.2, 6.3], Math.floor);` 

You can import it with `import _ from "lodash";`