# Combine items in list based on id

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list containing items where some items have the same id. The list contains an id property (string) and a quantity product (decimal). I want to iterate through the list and combine those elements with the same id.

If the list has 4 elements with the following values

```
    id = 1 quantity = 1,
    id = 1 quantity = 2,
    id = 2 quantity = 2,
    id = 3 quantity = 3,
```

then I want to create a new list where the two elements with the id of 1 are merged into a single element and the new list should look like this instead.

```
    id = 1 quantity = 3,
    id = 2 quantity = 2,
    id = 3 quantity = 3,
```

I want to do this using Linq and could not find any useful examples. The important part is that I don't want to lose any elements and want to combine the quantity value of elements with the same id.

I have tried using for loops and the code got too messy and couldn't work without using all types of if statements to compare values.

Comment: You are looking to `GroupBy` the `id` value. After that, select the `Sum` of `quantity`. Something like `list.GroupBy(item => item.id).Select(group => new { id = group.Key, quantity = group.Sum(item => item.quantity) } )`

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34659744/6522011) answer for reference if using Javascript

Answer (score 3):

You must group the items

```cs
var groupedItems = items
    .GroupBy(i => i.id)
    .Select(g => new Item{ id = g.Key, quantity = g.Sum(i => i.quantity));
```

This produces an `IEnumerable<Item>`. You can also add a `.ToList()` to create a list of items.

Note that groups, besides storing the group value into the `Key` property, implement `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is the type of the elements being grouped. Therefore, you can apply `.Sum()` to the group.

Alternatively, you can specify what has do be grouped in a second argument to `GroupBy`:

```cs
var groupedItems = items
    .GroupBy(i => i.id, i => i.quantity)
    .Select(g => new Item{ id = g.Key, quantity = g.Sum());
```

Now, we can omit the argument to `Sum`, since the groups now contain quantities instead of items.

---

You also mentioned that you don't want to lose items. You could achieve this by creating a record type storing the result:

```cs
public record ItemTotals(int Id, int Quantity, List<Item> Items);
```

```cs
var groupedItems = items
    .GroupBy(i => i.id)
    .Select(g => new ItemTotals{
        Id = g.Key,
        Quantity = g.Sum(i => i.quantity),
        Items = g.ToList()
    });
```

But it depends what you need. Alternatives: Create a custom class or struct, use tuples, create an anonymous type, ...

Answer (score 0):

If I suppose data type is like
`public record Product(int Id, decimal Quantity);`,
then you can use `GroupBy` method on `Id` and which will return `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>` where `TKey` is the type of the key used for grouping (`int` in this case) and `TElement` is the type of the elements in the group (`Product` in this case).

Then you can use `Select` method to create a new `Product` object for each group. The `p.Key` expression is used to set the `Id` property of the new `Product` object to the group key, and the `p.Sum(p => p.Quantity)` expression is used to set the `Quantity` property of the new `Product` object to the sum of the quantities in the group. Finally, the `ToList` method is used to convert the resulting sequence to a `List<Product>`.

```
var result = products
    .GroupBy(p => p.Id) 
    .Select(p => new Product(p.Key, p.Sum(p => p.Quantity)))
    .ToList();
```